# Find index of SKSpriteNode in an Array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Currently trying to access the index of nodes within an array with...

```
let menuArray = [firstNode, secondNode, thirdNode]

for arrayNode in menuArray {
        let index = menuArray.index(of:arrayNode)
}
```

returns error "Cannot invoke "index" with an argument list of type '(of: Optional)'

Comment: why are first,second, and third nodes optional?  You would have to unwrap it with let menuArray = [firstNode!, secondNode!, thirdNode!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want access `index` also in for loop with object then you can use `enumerated()` with your for loop.

```
for (index, arrayNode) in menuArray.enumerated() {
    //access index and arrayNode
}
```